# Netbeans regular expression search and replace

Tags: regex, netbeans, replace

I would like to find and replace in project on netbeans by using regular expression.

Find 
$_SESSION['anything']['anything']

Replace with
$this->Session->read('anything.anything');

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

You could accomplish this in the following way ...

***Find*** `\$_SESSION\['(.*?)'\]\['(.*?)'\]`

***Replace with*** `\$this->Session->read('$1.$2');`

see **[regex demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/ioGsnE/1)**

Comment: Thanks for your response. The find expression is working good, but for the Replace with $this->Session->read('$1.$2'); shows en error "Replace with field contains invalid expression".

Comment: Ok, I got it. The correct replace expression would be \$this->Session->read('$1.$2');